# How to center text in 100% width fixed image

Tags: css, position, css-position, fixed, absolute

I have an image (picture of a lawn) styled with the following:

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    position: fixed; <!-- top of page-->
}
```

I have an `<h1> Putnam Lawn Care</h1>` that I would like to have overlap and be centered in the image, but am unsure how to do this with css (I have tried `position:fixed; top: 20%; left: 50%;` but this puts the 'P' of 'Putnam Lawn Care' at 50% so this is also not centered) ? Also I am unsure if fixed positioning is correct here, should I be using absolute? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work. This can place the h1 tag in 100% width and text inside that will be center aligned.

```
h1{
    position:fixed; 
    top: 20%;
    width:100%;
    text align: center;
}
```

Since you used `position:fixed` for the image, it is better to use fixed position for `<h1>` also.This will help to stick the `<h1>` always with image.

Comment: The image seems to be covering the h1 text?

Comment: use z-index, in case you applied z-index for <img>, apply a bigger value for <h1>. other wise z-index:1 will be enough

Comment: this worked! thank you very much for the quick reply and the h1 100% width was a very clever solution

Comment: Cheers @user9708733!

Answer (score 1):

Here's with a dynamic image size and wrapping element.

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Loreum!</h1>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Loreum Pics">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just put both the `img` and the `h1` tag in an enclosing div, and then do the absolute positioning on that div - this will be more maintainable because you won't have to be setting `position: absolute` on multiple elements